# Edit rejected: is it possible to respond to this?

Tags: discussion, editing

The rejection of edits seems to be final. Isn't it possible to argue the case?

I have my own rejected edit in mind — suggested edit to: *When is a gerund supposed to be preceded by a possessive pronoun?*

[StackExchange ELU 'When is a gerund supposed to be preceded by a possessive pronoun?'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6756/usage-of-the-gerund-preceded-by-the-possessive-pronoun)

[rejected edit suggestion about the title, replacing 'pronoun' with 'adjective or determiner'](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/166910)

I mean, who would dare (to) say that possessive pronouns (mine, yours, his, hers, its, ours, theirs) and possessive adjectives or determiners (my, your, his, her, its, our, their) are the same thing?

Comment: Can you link an edit that was rejected? I tried to find it [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history), but I can't find any edit related with your question.

Comment: @Rathony When I click on "here" in your comment, I get the list of my own edits.  Is this a feature of the programming, did you make a mistake, or did you assume that if an edit caused extreme upset it must be mine? :)

Comment: @ab2 Sorry, I think only users with more than 10,000 reputation points could see the link. It shows all the history of edit approval and rejection. The link I wanted to find is in the question. (2nd link).

Comment: You had two recourses: (1) Post an answer in which you point out the error in the title of the question -- and, of course, answer the question.  (2) Edit the question again, with a fuller explanation of why the change is needed.  Rathony has done (2).  As for answering an old question, OK only if the answers are inadequate, IMO.  The best solution is to get 755 more rep points by answering new questions.

Comment: I suspect that some of your consternation may be due to the phrasing of the rejection reasons. Please note that the first is a 'canned' explanation that is generated when the 'too minor' rejection choice is selected. The wording of this explanation has been criticized and some (including me) are advocating that [we should change it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242159/the-new-edit-rejection-message-for-no-improvement-whatsoever-sounds-too-hostil).

Comment: @KitZ.Fox: political correctness is paramount…

Answer (score 4):

You appear to have misunderstood what editing is for. It is not to 'correct' somebody else's argument; otherwise every post would constantly be overwritten by those who disagree. Rather it is to improve the quality of the post, rather than the content.

If you disagree with an answer to any question, you can (and should) post your own competing answer.  Since you are obviously right (even though, since you didn't include a link, I haven't seen the question) your answer will gain lots of upvotes and everybody will be happy.

Comment: it is not the argument that should be corrected, but the title! A pronoun and an adjective are not the same thing!

Comment: @user58319 You should have linked the edit so that TimLymington could find what the edit is all about. Your question is misleading and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I understand what happened. I have just edited the post.

When you have more than 2,000 reputation points, you can edit the post without having to go through the review process. Until then, you can try the followings:

1. Please try to state clearly what the purpose of your edit is in **Edit Summary** so that reviewers can understand what your intention is. But note that it can never prevent 100% a good edit from being rejected. We all make a mistake sometimes.
2. When you are sure about the mistake, you can re-edit the post.

Comment: @user58319 I didn't say you made a mistake. We all make a mistake. The question is 5 years old and nobody could notice it. Are you blaming all the members of this community?

Comment: I think 2,000 reputation points granting anyone the privilege of editing posts without having to go through the review process is too few (points needed) and too much (of a privilege)!

Comment: I'm not sure whether you should have edited it. Linguistic terminology is not always universally consistent, and if either of you disagreed then it would probably have been more appropriate to discuss it in an answer.

Comment: @curiousdannii The OP is correct and we should not call them possessive pronouns. Possessive pronouns are mine, ours, yours, etc.

Comment: @Rathony Sure, but many people would probably consider possessive determiners to also be a kind of pronoun. Functionally there's lots of overlap for all these words.